# Codeigniter - Store requested url if not logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, session, input

In my site, if the session expired or they logged out, they have to log back in, in order to get into the members area. Now for example, if they want to do something like this

```
http://example.com/site/approve_friend_request/RaNdOmCoDe
```

You are allowed to only finish approving a friend request, for example, inside the members area. But if they are not logged in, they are redirected to (for example)

```
http://example.com/login_form
```

I want to know what some ideas are to store the requested url and direct them there once they successfully logged in. I have some ideas, but not sure what the best approach would be. Ideally I wouldn't want to store any info in the url, unless it is a good approach:

```
http://example.com/login_form/redirect_after_loggin/approve_friend_request/RaNdOmCoDe
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: store it in the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, thank you so much for your help. I do have a few options and seems like the easiest is:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('last_url' => current_url()));
```

It stores even if I'm not logged in and stays after the login. Once I redirected I removed it using

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('last_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the way Facebook does it, whether it is a good approach or not I would leave that up to you.

Lets say you want to redirect the user to *http://www.google.com* after log in.

```
$redirect_url = json_encode('http://www.google.com');
header( 'Location: http://site.com/login_form?redirect_url=' . $redirect_url );
```

Make sure the URL parameters **redirect_url** gets passed from page to page, after user log in, check if redirect_url is set, if it is:

```
$redirect_url = json_decode($_GET['redirect_url']);
header('Location: $redirect_url');
```